# how to add an open_basedir path in nginx vhost

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, open-basedir

In php.ini I've set

```
open_basedir = /home/user/web/
```

Now I would like to run phppgadmin on a subdomain which needs to include files from /usr/share/phppgadmin.
So I added the following line to the nginx-config for this host:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/home/user/web/:/usr/share/phppgadmin/";
```

and restarted nginx. However, I can't access the site because of following error:

> [error] 31440#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Warning:  include_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/phppgadmin/libraries/lib.inc.php) is not within the allowed path(s): **(/home/user/web/)** in /usr/share/phppgadmin/info.php on line 10

What could be the reason that the 2nd path isn't listed here? What else do I need to add an open_basedir to a virtual host? I only used the default file in /sites-available.

**edit** Always think of restarting fpm...

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your particular situation, you should consider just adding `/usr/share` to the default `open_basedir`, since anything in there is designed to be read by the world anyway.

Plus, `open_basedir` is easily circumvented unless you have locked down `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system` and similar PHP functions so don't consider secured for using it (I know, it sucks).

If you're wondering how you can circumvent it easily, you can just `system('php -n ascript.php');`. The `-n` will cause no PHP.ini to be read, so no `open_basedir` will be applied.

Comment: thanks, I will keep in mind (and deactivate open_basedir). The problem of reloading ini was another one, I edited in my question.

Comment: But if you don't need these functions you can easily disable them in php.ini

Answer (score 6):

Just FYI, if you have nginx configs set for multiple vhosts (so, configs in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`) then you may need to set the `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir=` there:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/var/www/:/new/path";
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring `open_basedir` via `fastcgi_param` may cause [some problems](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,234856) when there are multiple sites on your server.

The other option is to use [.user.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) .